DAViCal: After rebuilding server, peer authentication failed for user davical_app
I have just rebuilt a server with PostgreSQL and DAViCal.
I added the following lines to pg_hba.conf (same config as on the old server):
local   davical    davical_app   trust
local   davical    davical_dba   trust

I did not run create_database.sh, but instead restored the database from dump using:
sudo -u postgres pg_restore -C -c --if-exists -d postgres /path/to/davical.post

I enabled DAViCal on the Apache server and, in /etc/davical/config.php, enabled pwauth.
After restarting Apache, when I connect to the server, I get a blank page instead of the login page – which has ususally been a sign of the database not being reachable. This is corroborated by the entries in /var/log/apache2/error.log:

Unable to connect to database: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "davical_app"
PHP Fatal error:  PDO connection error 'pgsql:dbname=davical user=davical_app': SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "davical_app" in /usr/share/awl/inc/AwlDBDialect.php on line 103

What gives?

The order of entries in pg_hba.conf matters.
On the old server, the two entries for DAViCal were the first ones.
On the new servers, I had placed the two entries at the end. After moving them to the top and restarting PostgreSQL, everything seems to work now.
